# redirect by domain does not work on the phone

Tags: nginx, mobile, dns, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want that when a person enters a domain name in the search, he will be redirected to the site, but this does not happen. For some reason it only works with https://. Can this be fixed and what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please specify the exact error you are receiving? like can you share your nginx config file?

Comment: @HariAcharya

```
server {
        server_name mydomain www.mydomain;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
        }

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/prop2p.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/prop2p.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

```

Here is my config. I get an error - unable to connect to the site

Answer (score 0):

please make sure of the following things. Usually, these things resolve the issue you are getting:

1. Clear the web browser cache, with CTRL+F5.
2. Check the NGINX web server logs
3. Check the redirect rules, in the NGINX configuration of the website.
4. Set the right file and folder permissions
5. Increase the webserver script timeout to be connected longer with NGINX

Doing those things usually comes to solving general issues with the nginx server. In case your problem is not resolved please try sharing a copy of your server logs and config file.